# Bulk insert using EntityFramework Extended

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-extended

According to [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/entity-framework-batch-994cd739), bulk insert in Entity can be made using the following code:

```
 var customers = GetCustomers();   
 db.Customers.AddRange(customers);   
 db.SaveChanges();
```

I used SQL Profiler to verify how many insert queries were executed and I saw there was an insert for each element of the list.

[image]

Why?

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior even after using that package?

Comment: Yes, I have only tried the insert and it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong because I added the package and it didn't change anything. The code is the same.

Comment: That post you linked has more code in it than you have included here.  For one thing, a custom DataContext with a DBSet is used.  Have you followed the post *exactly?*   Are you using Entity Framework 6, as specified by the post?

Comment: There is a sample solution [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Entity-Framework-Batch-994cd739/view/SourceCode#content).  You should try that before declaring that it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm also using a custom Context that inherits from DbContex and contains a DbSet.

Comment: Try the sample solution.

Comment: That's the same example

Comment: No.  *The exact solution,* file for file.  Byte for byte.  Either it works, and you're done, or it doesn't work and you file a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: Hehehe, Ok, I will try using the exact same example. I will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: The thing is that linked article is misleading: they don't insert in bulk, rather using standard API. Only then they install the package and use its API to update in bulk, etc.

Comment: Also see [tag:entity-framework-extended] wiki: "Entity Framework Extended provides batch *updates, deletes and queries* for Entity Framework".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AddRange**

Add range doesn't perform a BulkInsert, it simply DetectChanges once after all entities are added to the set.

The DetectChange method can be VERY slow.

See: [Entity Framework - DetectChanges Performance](http://entityframework.net/improve-ef-detect-changes-performance)

As you noticed, it saves entities one by one in the database which is INSANELY slow.

**EF.Extended**

This library is not longer supported, and there is no Bulk Insert feature.

**Bulk Insert Library**

There is three major library supporting Bulk Insert:

- [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/) (*Paid but supported*)
- [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/) (*No longer supported*)
- [EFUtilities](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFUtilities/) (*No longer supported*)

Be careful, both free libraries don't support all inheritances and associations.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

In addition of Bulk Insert, this library allows you to perform all bulk operations:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge
- BulkSynchronize

Example:

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```

Comment: What if I try creating a Stored Procedure to achieved the bulk insert? I will  be calling the stored procedure from EntityFramework.

Comment: Stored Procedure will not be as fast as any of Bulk Insert Library and will require more time on your part, but you will get for sure performance enhancement over standard way to insert with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 3):

That's how EF6 does "bulk" insert, it doesn't do in bulk, rather row by row. As a result performance sucks.

Use [EF.BulkInsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/) or [EFUtilities](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFUtilities/) instead.

Comment: The post he linked states that `EntityFramework.Extended` is being used.  See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Entity-Framework-Batch-994cd739/sourcecode?fileId=150452&pathId=2085240737

Comment: What does your update mean?  It doesn't work because he isn't really using EF.Extended, or that he doesn't need EF.Extended at all?

Comment: That's the point. I'm not really sure if I'm using EF.Extended. I installed it but the code does not reference EF.Extended anyware.

Comment: From [EF.Extended's readme](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/readme.md) I don't see it offers bulk insert functionality in the first place.

Comment: @LuisTeijon: my recommendation is to use EF.BulkInsert. It doesn't support other operations in bulk, i.e. no update, delete. However insert works perfectly. In my previous project we were inserting thousands of rows, several million per month. Without issues. It also support `SqlBulkCopyOptions` what is important if you want to check/enforce constraints.

Comment: DbSet<T>.AddRange() also does one insert for each element in the list (except in EF Core)

Comment: Bulk ops are supported with [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)
Disclaimer: I'm the author.